# scrapy import itemloaders ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itemloaders'

Tags: python, scrapy

I had a scrapy project working with version 2.0 but when I upgraded to version 2.4 I am getting the above error.

It seems the be failing in the init.py file below:
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader_*init*_.py

on this import line which didn't exist in version 2.0:

```
import itemloaders
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: `pip install itemloaders`? Just guessing.

Comment: `from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader`

Answer (score 2):

Itemloader changed in scrapy 2.3

From scrapy v.2.3 [release notes](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-2-3-0-2020-08-04):

> The base implementation of item loaders has been moved into a separate
> library, [itemloaders](https://itemloaders.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), allowing usage from outside Scrapy and a
> separate release schedule

Answer (score 0):

It is given in the documentation example about Item Loaders. You have to import ItemLoader from scrapy.loader. Link : https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comments say, it's all laid out in the documentation.
That being said, I changed the following import statement

`from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader`

to

`from itemloaders import ItemLoader`

and it worked.